# how to add space after every word and separate digits from word?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

here is my string

```
text = 'EffectsRelaxed96% VotedHappy79% VotedEuphoric67% Voted'
```

I tried this:

```
add_space_after_word =  re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", text)
>>>'Effects Relaxed96% Voted Happy79% Voted Euphoric67% Voted'
seperate_digites_from_words = 'Effects Relaxed96% Voted Happy79% Voted Euphoric67% Voted'
re.sub(r"(\d\d)", r" \1", seperate_digites_from_words)
>>>'Effects Relaxed 96% Voted Happy 79% Voted Euphoric 67% Voted'
```

my expected result will be:

```
'Effects: Relaxed 96% Voted, Happy 79% Voted, Euphoric 67% Voted'
```

is there any way I can do this in a single line of code instead of writing two line of code? also I want to add comma after word Voted and want to add semicolon after word Effects.

Comment: Maybe something like https://ideone.com/3fMxos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
text = 'EffectsRelaxed96% VotedHappy79% VotedEuphoric67% Voted'
print( re.sub(r'([a-z])([A-Z0-9])', r'\1 \2', text).replace("Effects", "Effects:").replace("Voted", "Voted,").rstrip(',') )
# => Effects: Relaxed 96% Voted, Happy 79% Voted, Euphoric 67% Voted
```

See the [Python code demo](https://ideone.com/3fMxos).

The `([a-z])([A-Z0-9])` regex matches a lowercase letter (capturing into Group 1) and then an uppercase letter or digit (capturing into Group 2). The  replacement is Group 1 and Group 2 with a space between them.

The colon and commas are added using mere `str.replace`, since the words are known.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew Thanks for your anware. is there any way we can remove specific comma ? here is my text = `,Side Effects:,,,Hallucination,Fatigue,Dry eyes,`  I just want to remove first comma and all commas after only semicolon so my expected result will be look like `Side Effects:Hallucination,Fatigue,Dry eyes,`

Comment: @boyenec Maybe `re.sub( r'^([^,]*),+', r'\1', text.strip(','))`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/3Hlenc).